# Winforms throws ArgumentOutOfRangeException when setting TabPage.Text

Tags: winforms, tabcontrol, tabpage

I have code like this

```
someTabPage.Text = "hello";
```

where `someTabPage` is a non-null instance of `System.Windows.Forms.TabPage` created by the Winforms designer.

Occasionally (no one can reproduce this yet) this exception is thrown

```
[System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException] InvalidArgument=Value of '-1' is not valid for 'index'.
Parameter name: index
  at System.Windows.Forms.TabControl.SetTabPage(Int32 index, TabPage tabPage, TCITEM_T tcitem)
  at System.Windows.Forms.TabControl.UpdateTab(TabPage tabPage)
  at System.Windows.Forms.TabPage.UpdateParent()
  at System.Windows.Forms.TabPage.set_Text(String value)
  at my code which calls the setter
```

I am looking at the source [starting from this point in the call stack](http://typedescriptor.net/browse/members/519700-System.Windows.Forms.TabPage.set_Text%28String%29) but I can't imagine what is wrong. As Ginosaji suggests in the comments, it seems that the parent-child relationship is broken - the TabPage is pointing to its parent TabControl, but the parent is not holding the child in its collection. I would think "race condition", but only the UI thread should be able to touch Winforms controls.

It might be worth noting that this TabControl is nested in another TabControl, but that doesn't give me any ideas.

Does anyone know why this could be happening?

**Progress**

I caught it in the debugger and confirmed that the parent-child relationship is indeed broken.

```
? tabPageProblem.Parent
{System.Windows.Forms.TabControl, TabPages.Count: 2, TabPages[0]: TabPage: {Unit Data}}
    System.Windows.Forms.TabControl: {System.Windows.Forms.TabControl, TabPages.Count: 2, TabPages[0]: TabPage: {Unit Data}}
? tabPageProblem.Parent.Name
"tabControlParent"
? tabControlParent.TabPages.Contains(tabPageProblem)
False
```

The tab page still has its Parent set, but the parent does not Contain the tab page.

Unfortunately, I still don't know how it got into this state.

Comment: Clearly `someTabPage` is actually `someTabControl.TabPages[-1]`. I can't tell you why without a code sample.

Comment: @Ginosaji no, `someTabPage` is actually an instance variable, not a more complex expression. If you look at the stack trace, you can see that the problem comes from further in the stack.

Comment: I looked at the .NET source. UpdateTab would only pass -1 to SetTabPage if the TabPage is not in the TabPages collection. That's interesting, to say the least. I'll see if I can find more for you.

Comment: As a temporary workaround, you may try removing the `TabPage` from the `TabControl` before setting the `Text`.

Comment: This will happen when you try to update a TabPage that is no longer part of the tab control.  Review the code that removes tab pages from the control and make sure that other code isn't holding a reference to the tabpage that got removed.

Comment: @Hans But under normal circumstances, you can set the text of a removed TabPage. If I do `tabControl.TabPages.Remove(page)` _or_ `page.Parent = null` I can still set `page.Text = "hello"` with no problem. Which makes me think our code is removing the TabPage in a very unorthodox way. I doubt it's using reflection to set the Parent to null, but it could be something equally foolish. Is there a best practice or common pitfalls for disconnecting a TabPage?

Comment: Yes, something unorthodox, the parent is still set.  A problem with threading jumps to mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been running into this error with .TabPages.Add and finally found a consistent repro and a solution that may help you:

Add in this new line:

```
    someTabPage.PerformLayout();
    someTabPage.Text = "hello";
```

Comment: We've gotten rid of the problem code since I asked this question, so I can't test it. But I'll take your word that it works, in which case it's much better than my workaround.

Comment: This did not help in my situation. See comment for answer below.

Answer (score 1):

You mentioned the issue happens in a child TabControl... Is the tabpage containing this child TabControl inactive when the Text is set? (Meaning a different tabpage of the parent TabControl is in the foreground.) I believe that while the child TabControl is not visible (being in a "background" tabpage) it has a tendency to behave unexpectedly.

Comment: Voting for this answer because it describes my situtaion 100% and there's no straightforward solution/workaround for that.

Comment: I've re-visited the issue and found a decent workaround for it. Call Show() and then Hide() the window containing the problematic elements. After this tab control behaves well even on a hidden window.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the workaround I used:

```
If tabControl.TabPages.Contains(tabPage) Then
    tabPage.Text = "the text"
ElseIf tabPage.Parent IsNot Nothing Then
    logger.Warn("there is still a problem with this tab page, parent is {0}", tabPage.Parent)
End If
```